# Zoom a map out where tiles contain a feature

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to determine at what zoom level a certain map feature exists and zoom out to that level?

So for instance, if I want to zoom out to a level where water is for instance. In my case, this might be the ocean so potentially I could zoom out until the altitude is 0, or I could flip that on its head and show the ocean, but zoom out until I see a shoreline (altitude of +1)

Yes I can see issues with using altitude as well... for example what if the map is showing a lake 2,000ft above sea level, but I thought it an interesting enough exercise to put it out there and see what comes back.

Comment: First, you may need to clarify your question a bit before people can give you a good answer. Do you want to adjust the view until a certain feature is visible? Until it is shown in appropriate detail? Second, web map tiles do not contain metadata about what kinds of features lie within them, so you would need some additional data (vector data of the oceans, say) to calculate the necessary zoom levels. Third, map projections (at least those used in web mapping) are not perspective views with an eye point looking down at the surface, so there is no equivalent "altitude" to a given zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

```
var marker = L.circle([lat,lon], 1, {
    color: '#fff',
    fillColor: '#fff',
    opacity: 0,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    }).addTo(map);

map.on('move', function() {
    bounds = map.getBounds();

    if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
        return;
    }else{
      console.log('can not find marker.');
    }
});
```

This will create an invisible marker with a custom longitude/latitude (so if you want it in the ocean, get the coordinates for that ocean position and set the lat/lon parameter in the marker).

Then whenever the map is moved (when the boundaries shift), it will run a check to see if your marker is currently visible. If it is visible, then no problem, no behavior necessary. If not? It can do whatever you want, you just need to replace the console log in the else condition with the the actual desired behavior.

Kind of a hacky way of doing it, but should achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: No really as using this method I need to put a marker on the edge of the land feature. It would be funky if I had for instance an "isWater" flag so I could check if the current bounds extended over any point on the map where there was a body of water.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "funky"... But you could just use multiple markers. This solution scales up to as many markers as you can create.

If you want to to be able to check if there is water specifically, then you will need to gather further geological data to map a water variable that can then be checked. ex: `if(bounds.contain()){}`